# How to setup Angularjs controllers? anonymous functions vs $scope.init() vs view ng-init

Tags: angularjs

Assume we have a controller: `ProjectsNewCtrl`

What is the difference between:

Setting up the controller without an `init()` function

```
App.controller('ProjectsNewCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'API'
  function ($scope, $location, API) {
    API.Project.query().$promise
      .then(function (projects) {
        $scope.projects = projects
      })
  }])
```

AND

Setting up the controller with an `init()` function

```
App.controller('ProjectsNewCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'API'
  function ($scope, $location, API) {
    $scope.init = function(){
      API.Project.query().$promise
        .then(function (projects) {
          $scope.projects = projects
        })
      }
    $scope.init()

  }])
```

AND finally:

Setting up the controller via:

```
<div ng-controller="projectsNewCtrl" ng-init="init()">...</div>

App.controller('ProjectsNewCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'API'
  function ($scope, $location, API) {
    $scope.init = function(){
      API.Project.query().$promise
        .then(function (projects) {
          $scope.projects = projects
        })
      }

  }])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real reason why you would want to use `ngInit` in this way. In your second example, you are calling a function(`ngInit`) to call a function(`$scope.init`), instead of the first example where you only call one function on initialization. The logic maybe the same, but it adds unnecessary complexity.

As an aside, you should try no to use `ngInit` as little as possible, coming from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Answer (score 0):

Preference. Your last 2 examples are essentially the same, the logic that should be ran on initialization is within the `init` method - one is called from the view and the other the controller. IMO - it's all about readability, choose what you like.